# atomic variables in C

Tags: c, multithreading, atomic

I would like to use atomic variables in C.

I tried the following suggested builtin functions in gcc but I received a link error `` undefined reference to `_sync_fetch_and_add' ``.

```
  type __sync_fetch_and_add (type *ptr, type value);
  type __sync_fetch_and_sub (type *ptr, type value);
  type __sync_fetch_and_or (type *ptr, type value);
  type __sync_fetch_and_and (type *ptr, type value);
  type __sync_fetch_and_xor (type *ptr, type value);
  type __sync_fetch_and_nand (type *ptr, type value);
```

I am assuming that my architecture doesn't support them..I thought that probably because it is not INTEL but looking a the CPU info I discovered that I have Intel CPU.

```
  >less /proc/cpuinfo

  processor       : 0
  vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
  cpu family      : 6
  model           : 26
  model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           X5570  @ 2.93GHz
  stepping        : 5
  cpu MHz         : 1600.000



   >uname -a
   Linux xxxxxx 2.6.24.7-108.el5rt #1 SMP PREEMPT RT 
   Mon Mar 23 10:58:10 EDT 2009      x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Do you know other ways or libraries that might implement atomic variables for my architecture or if am I doing something wrong( maybe some compilation flags that I hould check out )?

NOTE: I found `stdatomic.h` but is for C++ only unfortunately

Usage example:

```
int i =0;
i = _sync_fetch_and_add (&i,2);
```

Comment: Could you show how you use these functions? It looks like you are missing one underscore out of two in function name `__sync_XXX`.

Comment: Well I feel a bit stupid 'cos now it compiles with no problem.You were right..I was missing the first underscore..:(

Comment: No problem, everyone can use a second pair of eyes once in a while :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This answer is going to become relevant in the year 201X. :-)

The upcoming C1X standard is to introduce atomics as a C language feature.
See the [draft C1X standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1548.pdf).

Comment: :) I even didn't know that also C was going versus its C1X versions. I personally focused last years only in C++ and C++0x that I even could believe C was going to progress as well. Thanks for the good updated.

Answer (score 2):

Try the -march command line option, the atomic builtins are not available for all target architectures. [See also](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Atomic-Builtins.html)

Comment: +1 In particular consider using `-march=native`. If your version of gcc doesn't support this, this is a good indication that it is too old. AFAIR versions up to 4.2 or so are a bit difficult in that they just leave the symbol undefined when they are not implementing this stuff.